# What is the problem with this custom security manager for Apache Superset?

Tags: python, apache-superset

I'm running Apache Superset **1.4.0** on a Debian server, inside a Python virtual environment.

I'm trying to implement a custom security manager, but I'm stuck because Apache Superset is complaining about imports.

My `superset` and `superset_config.py` are in `/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/` directory.

I've created a new `custom_security_manager.py` file in the same directory, that is `/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin`, with the following contents:

```
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import UserDBModelView,AuthDBView

class CustomAuthDBView(AuthDBView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        if token == 'SOME_TOKEN_VALUE':
            login_user('some_user_name', remember=False)
        else:
            flash('Unable to auto login', 'warning')
            return super(CustomAuthDBView,self).login()

class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authdbview = CustomAuthDBView
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```

My `superset_config.py` has the following contents:

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True,
}

from custom_security_manager import CustomSecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager
```

When I start the Superset service and then check the logs, I see the following:

```
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]: Found but failed to import local superset_config
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/superset/config.py", line 1298, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:     import superset_config  # pylint: disable=import-error
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset_config.py", line 5, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/custom_security_manager.py", line 4, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/custom_security_manager.py", line 7, in CustomAuthDBView
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset", line 11, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:     load_entry_point('apache-superset==1.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'superset')()
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/superset/cli.py", line 39, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:     from superset import app, appbuilder, config, security_manager
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/lib/python3.9/site-packages/superset/config.py", line 1298, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:     import superset_config  # pylint: disable=import-error
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/superset_config.py", line 5, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/custom_security_manager.py", line 4, in <module>
Jan 28 13:46:46 dashboard-server python[17190]:   File "/home/administrator/venv-superset/bin/custom_security_manager.py", line 7, in CustomAuthDBView
```

If I put `custom_security_manager.py` in the wrong directory, where should I put it?

Or is it about the `import` lines inside `custom_security_manager.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was missing some `imports` in my `custom_security_manager.py`.

When I modified it as the following, Apache Superset didn't complain anymore:

```
from flask import redirect, g, flash, request
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import UserDBModelView,AuthDBView
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import expose
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user

class CustomAuthDBView(AuthDBView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self):
        token = request.args.get('token')
        if token == 'SOME_TOKEN_VALUE':
            login_user('some_user_name', remember=False)                
        else:
            flash('Unable to auto login', 'warning')
            return super(CustomAuthDBView,self).login()

class CustomSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authdbview = CustomAuthDBView
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(CustomSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```